# How to pass a soup object in a JSON payload prepared for requests.put method in python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to read a web page using requests module in python, scrape the read data using beautifulsoup, modify the data in the soup object and write it back to the same web page using requests.put() method.

Is there anything that I got to do additionally in the soup object to get it assigned to the JSON payload?

Modules used for this purpose: 
1. JSON
2. requests
3. BeautifulSoup

If the JSON payload that I'm preparing is without soup object, then the requests.put() writes the data properly

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get(confluenceServerURL+getPageURL, verify=False, headers=headers)
# 200 OK is the response for the web page is accessible
if response.status_code == 200:
  jsonD = response.json()
  pageId =  jsonD["results"][0]['id']
  versionNum = jsonD["results"][0]['version']['number']
  body =  jsonD["results"][0]['body']['storage']['value']
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
  input_str = "test string"
  testMan = "found string"
  for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    for node in row.find_all('td'):
      if node.text == testMan:
        node.string = input_str
  newBody = soup
else: #response.status_code
  logger.error("Error while obtaining page with given page title %s ", response.status_code)
  exit(1);
## Space to write confluence page
logger.info('--------------Updating page--------------')
updatePageURL = "/rest/api/content/"+pageId

jsonPayload = {"id":pageId,"type":"page","title":pageTitle,"space":{"key":spaceKey},
               "body":{"storage":{"value":"{0}".format(newBody),"representation":"storage"}},
               "version":{"number":int(versionNum)+1}}
#print(jsonPayload)
# update page
response = requests.put(confluenceServerURL+updatePageURL,verify=False,data=json.dumps(jsonPayload),headers=headers)
logger.debug('URL for updating page is %s', response.url)
if response.status_code == 200:
  logger.info("Page with id %s updated successfully",pageId)
  #break;
else:
  logger.error("Unable to update page with id %s",pageId)
  logger.error(response.text)
```

I get the response code as 200 for request.put() but the page remains empty if beautifulsoup is being used. If it is directly in JSON format, the page is getting updated successfully

INFO:conf_rest_get_page:--------------Getting page -------------------
DEBUG:conf_rest_get_page:Getting SMSESSION from URL 
Accessible
DEBUG:conf_rest_get_page:URL for getting confluence page is  URL

INFO:conf_rest_get_page:--------------Updating page ----------------
INFO:conf_rest_get_page:Page with id 261042277 updated successfully

---

2019-06-09 10.26.58 =====  table procedure Ended, Status :  True  =====

Comment: Update: The latest error that I get is a HTTP bad request.

ERROR:conf_rest_get_page:{"statusCode":400,"data":{"authorized":false,"valid":true,"allowedInReadOnlyMode":true,"errors":[],"successful":false},"message":"Error parsing xhtml: Unexpected character '\\' (code 92) in start tag Expected a quote\n at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1206]","reason":"Bad Request"}